How to Update Opt-in/Opt-out Status for Mobile Push and SMS in SFMC Similar to Email Automation?
I have a Preference Center in SFMC where users can opt-in or opt-out of Mobile Push notifications and emails.
For emails, I’ve set up an automation that checks the subscriber status in the Preference Center (whether the status is active or not). Then, I update the statuses in All Subscribers using an export DE, file transfer, and import process.
My question is: How can I achieve the same for Mobile Push and SMS? Is there a way to update the opt-in/opt-out status for Mobile Push and SMS contacts in SFMC in a similar automated manner? Any guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

It's not possible. For Mobile Push the only way is to update the status by SDK and API. However, it's easy to go over the API limit.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Are you sure it's not possible?
